# Coleta de dado tipo float de um Widget Entry - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Estou desenvolvendo um programa para cálculos de engenharia civil e estou com um problema no resultado colido em um Widget Entry, esse mesmo Entry está contigo em um condição if como é mostrado no código abaixo, porém, quando tento usar o valor digitado nesse campo, o resultado obtido sempre é 0. Ja tentei coletar como String e converter pra float, mas aparece um erro que diz que não foi possível converter. O erro aparece na Função confirmar1, na condicionante if == 1.

```
# ...
if Vrd < Vd:

    bws = str("Utilize uma largura mínima de viga de %.f cm" % ((Vd / (0.2 * he * fcd)) * 100))
    fcks = str("Utilize um Fck mínimo de %.f MPa" % (1.4 * Vd / (200 * bw * he)))

    # Janela de verificação de cisalhamento
    verificacao1 = Tk()
    verificacao1.title("ERRO NA VERIFICAÇÃO")
    verificacao1.geometry("+300+100")

    # Frames
    frame_top1 = Frame(verificacao1)
    frame_top1.pack()
    frame_sugestoes = Frame(verificacao1)
    frame_sugestoes.pack(side=LEFT)

    def bt_click_nao1():
        verificacao1.destroy()
        return

    def bt_click_sim1():
        bt_sim1["state"] = "disabled"
        global raid11
        raid11 = IntVar()

        def ck1():
            ck_Afck["state"] = "disabled"
            en_fck["state"] = "disabled"
            global teste
            teste = 1
            return

        def ck2():
            ck_Alargura["state"] = "disabled"
            en_largura["state"] = "disabled"
            global teste
            teste = 2
            return

        def reset():
            ck_Alargura["state"] = "normal"
            ck_Afck["state"] = "normal"
            ck_Alargura.deselect()
            ck_Afck.deselect()
            en_largura["state"] = "normal"
            en_fck["state"] = "normal"
            en_largura.delete(first=0, last=11)
            en_fck.delete(first=0, last=11)
            return

        def confirmar1():
            verificacao1.destroy()

            if teste == 1:

                *bw1 = raid11.get() * 0.01*
                # Carregamento
                Q = (bw1 * h * 25) + Gi + Gs
                # print(f'#Novo Carregamento: \033[33m{Q:.2f} KN/m\033[m')

                # Esforços Solicitantes
                V = (Q * le) / 2
                M = (Q * pow(le, 2)) / 8
                # print(f'#Nova Cortante: \033[33m{V:.2f} KN\033[m')
                # print(f'#Novo Momento Máximo: \033[33m{M:.2f} KN.m\033[m')

                # Verificação do Concreto
                # Cisalhamento
                fcd = (fck * 1000) / 1.4
                Vrd = 0.20 * bw1 * he * fcd
                Vd = 1.4 * V
                print(f'#Nova cortante de cálculo: \033[33m{Vd:.2f} KN\033[m')
                print(f'#Nova resistênca de cálculo: \033[33m{Vrd:.2f} KN\033[m')

            if teste == 2:

                # Carregamento

                Q = (bw * h * 25) + Gi + Gs
                # print(f'#Novo Carregamento: \033[33m{Q:.2f} KN/m\033[m')

                # Esforços Solicitantes
                V = (Q * le) / 2
                M = (Q * pow(le, 2)) / 8
                # print(f'#Nova Cortante: \033[33m{V:.2f} KN\033[m')
                # print(f'#Novo Momento Máximo: \033[33m{M:.2f} KN.m\033[m')

                # Verificação do Concreto
                # Cisalhamento
                fcd = (fck * 1000) / 1.4
                vrd = 0.20 * bw * he * fcd
                Vd = 1.4 * V
                # print(f'#Nova cortante de cálculo: \033[33m{Vd:.2f} KN\033[m')
                # print(f'#Nova resistênca de cálculo: \033[33m{Vrd:.2f} KN\033[m')

                # Zona de Apoio
                Vd1 = Vd * 1.1
                Vrd1 = 0.8 * bw * (c1 + hf) * fcd
                print(f'Solicitação na zona de apoio: \033[33m{Vd1:.2f} KN\033[m')
                print(f'Resistência da zona de apoio: \033[33m{Vrd1:.2f} KN\033[m')
            return

        # textos e CheckButtons de escolha
        lb_escolaSolucao = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="ESCOLHA A SOLUÇÃO:", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), pady=10,
                                 bd=3, fg="#1E90FF", anchor="center")
        lb_escolaSolucao.grid(row=0, column=3)
        ck_Alargura = Checkbutton(frame_sugestoes, text="Aumentar largura", font=("Segoe UI", 12), command=ck1)
        ck_Alargura.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
        ck_Afck = Checkbutton(frame_sugestoes, text="Aumentar o Fck", font=("Segoe UI", 12), command=ck2)
        ck_Afck.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

        # Entrada de dados
        en_largura = Entry(frame_sugestoes, font=("Century Gothic", 11), textvariable=raid11, bd=5, insertwidth=4,
                           width=12, bg="#1E90FF", justify="right")
        en_largura.grid(row=1, column=4)
        en_fck = Entry(frame_sugestoes, font=("Century Gothic", 11), textvariable=raid12, bd=5, insertwidth=4,
                       width=12, bg="#1E90FF", justify="right")
        en_fck.grid(row=2, column=4)

        # botões reset e confirmar
        bt_reset = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="RESET", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=16, pady=0,
                          bd=2, width=7, command=reset)
        bt_reset.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
        bt_confirmar1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="CONFIRMAR", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=16,
                               pady=0, bd=2, width=7, command=confirmar1)
        bt_confirmar1.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)

    # Textos
    lb_alerta1 = Label(frame_top1, text="A ESTRUTURA NÃO SUPORTA O EFEITO DE CISALHAMENTO NO CONCRETO",
                       font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), pady=12, fg="#1E90FF")
    lb_alerta1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    lb_psugestoes = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="POSSÍVEIS SOLUÇÕES", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), pady=10, bd=3,
                          fg="#1E90FF")
    lb_psugestoes.grid(row=0, column=0)
    lb_largura = Label(frame_sugestoes, text=bws, font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_largura.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_fck = Label(frame_sugestoes, text=fcks, font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_fck.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_quest1 = Label(frame_sugestoes, text="Deseja aplicar alguma solução? ", font=("Segoe UI", 12))
    lb_quest1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    lb_linha1 = Label(frame_sugestoes)
    lb_linha1.grid(row=3, column=0)

    # botões - SIM/NÃO
    bt_sim1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="SIM", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=8, pady=0, bd=2,
                     width=5, command=bt_click_sim1)
    bt_sim1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
    bt_nao1 = Button(frame_sugestoes, text="NÃO", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="#1E90FF", padx=8, pady=0, bd=2,
                     width=5, command=bt_click_nao1)
    bt_nao1.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
    verificacao1.mainloop()
```

Bem, explicando mais sobre minha dúvida. Esse programa faz verificações de segurança, o `if` no início declara que se a solicitação for maior que a resistência o programa deve executar todo o bloco (gigante) abaixo. Bem nesse bloco é criada uma nova janela pequena que serve somente para alertar o usuário de que há um erro e convenientemente apontar uma solução para o erro, o usuário deve digitar um novo valor para o dado que irá corrigir o problema (Ex. largura de 15cm da erro, mas com 18cm é o suficiente, o usuário pode digitar os 18cm ou um valor maior). O problema é que não estou conseguindo capturar esse novo valor. E em resposta ao jsbueno, já tentei usar o `float`. E esse `* 0.01` é simplesmente uma multiplicação do valor capturado (usuário digitar em cm e o programa faz os cálculos em m).

Comment: Boa noite, Amigo voce poderia me explicar essa linha? *bw1 = raid11.get() * 0.01* N mexo muito no tkinter, mas não entendi a desses asteriscos no inicio e no fim.

Comment: Não sei qual é o propósito de você colocar esse trecho inteiro do programa dentro de um `if` global - é provável que você tenha aprendido a programar por conta. Isso funciona, mas não é uma pratica muito usada (na verdade, é tão estranha, que não chega sequer a ser uma prática "não recomendada", por que acho que ninguem acha que alguém sairia fazendo código assim). 

Bom, isso não afeta sua dúvida ou pergunta, mas fica a dica para uma revisão do programa. E pode afastar pessoas que iriam tentar sanar sua dúvida. "Nossa, esse código está tão louco que não vou nem olhar".

Comment: @JunyorSilva: o tkinter não interfere na sintaxe do Python. Essa linha vai dar erro de sintaxe - até existe uma forma de ter * num assignment, do tipo "*a, b = (1,2,3)` - nesse caso, "a" ficaria com o "começo da sequência exceto o último elemento" `(1, 2)` e `b` teria 3. Mas nesse caso é só sintaxe errada mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O  `.get` sempre vai retornar uma string. Se você deseja usar esse conteúdo como número decimal, chamar `float` no valor retornado pelo `.get()` é a coisa certa a se fazer.

Provavelmente quando você tentou deve ter errado alguma coisa - por exemplo, a linha `*bw1 = raid11.get() * 0.01*` contém dois erros de sintaxe-  o "*" como prefixo de variáveis para atrbuição até existe em Python, mas quando você precisar do mesmo, vai saber oq ue está fazendo - não é como em C, quem dependendo de como o código é escrito, você pode ter um ponteiro ou não e ter que alterar direto a variável, ou o conteúdo da posição apontada.  Em suma: esqueça esses asteriscos.

Como a única linha onde tem um `get` é justamente essa, tente:

```
bw1 = float(raid11.get()) * 0.01
```

Mais: já que você está usando uma variável global para passar informações para suas funções, ponha a declaração de `global` na primeira linha de todas as funções em que for mudar o valor da variável (e não imediatamente antes de usa-la). Em Python,  é uma questão de estilo, mas é um estilo *bem* recomendado. E, como já mencionei no comentário, fica bem estranho declarar funções e construir interfaces inteiras dentro do bloco de um `if` no corpo do módulo - melhor é sempre declarar todas as funções incondicionalmente, e ter uma função que "controla" o que acontece -dentro dela pode estar esse `if`, e ela dispara ou não a chamada de outras funções para construir partes da interface.